# Oracle 19.5 giving ORA-39358 for 19.0 dump

Tags: oracle, impdp

I am importing 19.0 dump (exported on Oracle 19.0c) on Oracle 19.5c oracle. But it give strange message as below,

```
Import: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Mar 23 05:46:48 2022
Version 19.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39358: Export dump file version 19.0.0.0.0 not compatible with target version 12.2.0.0.0
```

Can anyone explain.

Here is the compatible parameter I have:

```
\`SQL\> SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter
WHERE name = 'compatible';  2

NAME
-

VALUE
-

compatible
12\.2.0
\`
```

Comment: [ORA-39358](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/errmg/ORA-38029.html#GUID-1B677A70-6415-4030-9B89-9518DBBF2E07): *Export dump file version string not compatible with target version string*
**Cause**: The Oracle Data Pump export job version was newer than the target compatibility version.

**Action**: Upgrade the target database to a compatibility level of at least the export job version, or rerun the export job with a job version that is lower than or equal to the compatibility version of the target database.

Comment: If you were able to find the `compatible` parameter, then what is not clear in the error message?

Comment: why 19.5 is not compatible with 19.0 is my question..

Comment: Also, why its showing 12.2 when dump is 19.0 and oracle is 19.5

Comment: What have you found when you Google  [Oracle compatible](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+compatible)? The first link I get is a documentation. Which additionally describes why you cannot import newer versions of data to older databases

Comment: The only valid answer for "Why is some parameter equal to some value?" is "Because someone had set it to that value".

Comment: Please understand the question - I have 19c which is higher than 12.2 but still this error

Comment: I understand your question, but you haven’t  read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/COMPATIBLE.html#GUID-6C57EE11-BD06-4BB8-A0F7-D6CDDD086FA9): *The COMPATIBLE **parameter** specifies the Oracle version number that **the database disk format must be compatible with**. The database can be downgraded to the version specified in the COMPATIBLE parameter or any later version.* You need to ask your DBA why they set this parameter to 12.2. It is **not an Oracle version**, but a **storage parameter**

Comment: I understand compatible parameter but here..
Dump : 19c
Importing Oracle: 19c

why error is about 12.2

Comment: Compatible parameter is what matters. It’s purpose is to make sure that you don’t use new functionality (to make testing easier), the consequence is you can’t import from an export which was taking with a higher compatibility as it could include those features. Either upgrade your compatible (and test) or take another export with a suitable version parameter

Comment: Data Pump is an utility, it's common for Oracle's utilities to display its version at startup. This is what the first line means. Then Version is the version of DB release. Then you see that this utility connects to the 19c database and opens 19.0.0.0.0 dump file. As already said you either need to upgrade your `compatible` parameter in the target or export from the source with [`version` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-BAA3B679-A758-4D55-9820-432D9EB83C68.htm#SUTIL110) specified as 12.2.0.0.0 (which may miss some objects that doesn't fit this version).